# How to run php code on 32 bit os mac

Tags: php, macos

I have been trying to run php on my 32-bit macbook pro. I've tried XAMPP and MAMP, both only offer 64-bit downloads. And so it hasn't worked.

I don't really know why I have to download so much to run php but apparently I do (I'm new to php), it's a bit annoying really... Am I supposed to?

I'd like to use sublime text 2 as my editor, so if anyone knows what I need to download and then how to use the download I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: you dont use wamp. xamp or wamp .. you just create virtual machine and install Linux server and than work... also vagrant would be nice to do this

Comment: How do I create a virtual machine?

Comment: Also is there a way to use sublime text that you know of?

Comment: you can check this https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-laravel-homestead though you dont need to use laravel